# How to impose hard wrap against my soft wrap wishes?

Tags: vim, line-breaks

Well, I'm a newb at Vim, so I'm guessing there's a 99% chance it's a user error!

Vim was soft wrapping long lines very nicely thank you, then a couple of days ago it started to insert hard wraps **but only when I had saved the file**.

I have been through `wrap`, `nolinebreak`, `textwidth`, `nolist`, and all combinations thereof to try to get softwrap back but to no avail. Heck, I even read the help pages. All of 'em.

Here's the relevant bits from my `.vimrc` (as you can tell, I'm getting desperate):

```
" Editing
set aw ai
set et ts=8 sts=2 sw=2 nu
set fo+=tcrqw fo-=o
set showmatch matchtime=5
set whichwrap=<,>,h,l,[,]
set cursorline
set nofoldenable
set wrap 
set linebreak
let mapleader = ","
```

I picked up this .vimrc from using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but only when I had saved the file.

This should hint to you that some plugin is touching the buffer Pre-Write.

Find out which it is by doing

```
:au BufWrite,BufWritePre,BufWriteCmd
:au FileWriteCmd,FileWritePre
```

To see where the trigger was installed from:

```
:verbose au BufWrite,BufWritePre,BufWriteCmd
:verbose au FileWriteCmd,FileWritePre
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the culprit, [Tim Pope](http://tpo.pe)'s [Vim Markdown plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown). Lovely plugin but personally prefer soft wraps, will have to find how to change it!

Answer (score 2):

I have a suspicion this is probably caused by your `fo` line.  Having "t" in the `formatoptions` option means that if a `textwidth` is set for the current buffer then vim will break lines at this width.  You may notice that this only happens for certain filetypes because different ftplugins may be setting `textwidth` without you knowing.

The next time you see this happening, I'd suggest running `:verbose set textwidth?` (with the question mark) and seeing if the value is set.  This command will also point you to where it was last set.

Another test would be to just remove "t" from your `fo` line and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I ran `:verbose set textwidth?` What is interesting is that before saving, it reports `textwidth=0` and doesnt' hard wrap. After saving , comes back with `textwidth=78 Last set from ~/.vimrc`. When I `:set textwidth=0` it still hardwraps! Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2):

Janus is another Vim plugin that fiddles with linewrap/linebreak and textwidth.

```
:verbose set tw?
```

told me:

```
textwidth=72
    Last set from ~/.vim/janus/vim/core/before/plugin/filetypes.vim
```

Now I just need to figure out the *right* incantation to disable that... for now, I just added `set textwidth=99` to my `~/.vimrc.after` file, but there may be a better way...

Comment: I ended up using the `~/.vimrc` snippet from http://superuser.com/questions/250112/textwidth-0-and-wrapwidth-0-in-vimrc-local-not-being-respected